# Django project without storing data in database

Tags: python, django, csv

I wrote a script to collect some informations about products offerred by few eShops. This script runs  once an hour and collects data to csv file. File is overwritten everytime so it contains currently offered products only. Csv file contains fields - shop name, price, vendor, description, size, picture URL, product page URL and looks like this (just two lines of about 1500 lines)

```
sklep-presto.pl, 149.90, real, Deck Davis Northern Light 8,38 Real, 8.38, https://www.sklep-presto.pl/pol_il_Deck-Davis-Northern-Light-8-38-Real-59111.jpg, https://www.sklep-presto.pl/product-pol-59111-Deck-Davis-Northern-Light-8-38-Real.html
sklep-presto.pl, 169.90, real, Deck Embossed Elite Ferguson 8,5 Real, 8.5, https://www.sklep-presto.pl/pol_il_Deck-Embossed-Elite-Ferguson-8-5-Real-56151.jpg, https://www.sklep-presto.pl/product-pol-56151-Deck-Embossed-Elite-Ferguson-8-5-Real.html
```

This script is also generating dictionary csv files - price, vendor, size. These files contain unique values from particular field form main csv file. For example vendor dictionary loks like this

```
almost,blind,chocolate,deathwish,foundation,goodwood,machine,real,zero
3,3,4,2,3,2,2,9,7
```

It contains vendor names and occurence count (in main csv).

I would like to make a web page using django but I have never been using django.

I would like to make a web page that will present 5 choice lists and search button on top. Choice lists will be vendor, from price, to price, from size, to size. I would like possible choices to be imported (from csv files) to these choise lists on web page every time the page is loaded.

I don't need to store anything in database because I want to use only current values that are stored in my csv files. Do I have to make djagno model and store data in database?

After search button is pressed I would like chosen values to be passed to my another script that will search the main csv against sarch criteria. Of course this script has to be started after search button is pressed. This script returns may return saerch results line by  line or as a list of lists.

I would like the search results to be displayed as tiles on web page. Every tile shoud present as picture and same text values below (name, price, etc.). Tiles should be aligned in columns and rows (20 products per web page).

I don't need to store search results in database because I want to use only current values that are passed from my search engine. Do I have to make djagno model and store data in database?

Can you point me similar porject that I can review to realize how I should do this?

Comment: Of course you don't have to store it in the database. But doing so would be *much* simpler and more flexible than using a CSV file.

Comment: I realize that DB is better way to store data but csv is as far only thing that I can do and I want to use django only for presenting data. The two scripts that I wrote are my first programming try in my life. So I wolud like to preserve more complex ways for my second try :)

Comment: You are just try to show the CSV information into template then why Django. Why not use Micro framework ( flask ) instead ?

Comment: "I realize that DB is better way to store data" => well actually a DB is mostly a better way to __read__ (search, query etc) your data. If it's for learning purpose only then well go ahead with CSV, and you'll soon find out why relational DBs are still so successfull ;)

Comment: @Raja Simon Very good question. I don't know. Is DB only the only advantage of django? I wolud also like to have possibility to use bootstrap in future.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers exactly. Is for learning and for fun. I have to start with the simplest solutions and see for myself what are the weeknesses

Comment: @MichałRzepecki Bootstrap are all static parts.. You can configure easily with Flask. Also in Django. Both are good. Choose your framework. But my solution is just store the file in project folder and in your views read that csv. Do you want me to answer it?

Comment: @Raja Simon Yes, please. Give me as many informations as you can.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to make djagno model and store data in database?

No.

> Can you point me similar porject that I can review to realize how I should do this?

You want a basic Django setup with one view, template and form. [Django tutorial project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/) should be a good place to start.

Answer (score -3):

From the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

If you don't want your model to create database tables you put `abstract=True` in the `Meta` class

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: And ? How is this going to be of any help to the OP ?

Comment: It could be valuable information but for now I don't know how to use this information but thanks.

Comment: @MichałRzepecki it's totally useless wrt/  your question.